# Suddenly my Unity3D Editor (2021.3.22f1) won't build Android APKs

Tags: unity-game-engine, error-handling

I hope this is something someone can help with. Please note, I am 12 years old and have found my way with Unity through Youtube tutorials and Googling my issues...I am not a developer as such (yet!)

My Unity APK build process is failing and I don't know why because I haven't changed anything. I get this error:

`UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in :0 > at > UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods > (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, > UnityEditor.BuildOptions > defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in > :0 > UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent > (int,intptr,bool&)`

I have tried a few things:

1. I've tried updating my Editor to 2021.3.22f1
2. Reimported the project
3. Deleted the Library folder and had it regenerated
4. Deleted the Plugins folder and had it regenerated

Me and my dad are at a dead end. Hope someone can help? Thanks in advance